# What's the optimal query when pulling data from one table using different columns in your main data table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have a table that looks like this:

| WOID | ClientID | VendorID | FactoryID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | C01 | V03 | F01 |
| 123457 | C01 | V04 | F02 |
| 123458 | C02 | V05 | F03 |
| 123459 | C03 | V06 | F04 |
| 123460 | C04 | V06 | F05 |
| 123461 | C05 | V03 | F02 |

And then we have a lookup address table containing address data like so:

| EntityID | Address | Country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C01 | … | USA |
| C02 | … | Canada |
| C03 | … | UK |
| C04 | … | China |
| C05 | … | China |
| V03 | … | China |
| V04 | … | China |
| V05 | … | China |
| V06 | … | China |
| F01 | … | Vietnam |
| F02 | … | China |
| F03 | … | Malaysia |
| F04 | … | China |
| F05 | … | China |

What would be the optimal way of pulling the address data from the address table? Would this be 3 left joins (1 for client, vendor and factory IDs)? Generally, what I would do in Power BI is to do 3 separate merges, but I would like to be able to do this natively in the query, but this is what I am thinking of doing in the query:

```
LEFT JOIN ADDRESS A ON DATA.ClientID = A.EntityID
LEFT JOIN ADDRESS B ON DATA.VendorID = B.EntityID
LEFT JOIN ADDRESS C ON DATA.FactoryID = C.EntityID
```

Comment: Yes, three left joins are the way to go (assuming EntityID is unique and indexed).

Comment: Three separate left joins is probably the right way to go. Looks like a rather poor design though. Just because they are all "entities" doesn't mean they should all be in the same table, unless they are exactly the same shape. Find better aliases than A B C , maybe C V F respectively.

Comment: @Charlieface I fully agree with you. Unfortunately, I've seen this design pattern in several poorly designed apps, two times now.

Comment: yes, the approach with 3 left joins is correct, I wouldn't worry about the performance, a good DBMS will not scan ADDRESS 3 times, it will load it in memory at first step (in case the table is relatively small) and then perform an fast index scan to make a join

Comment: @TheImpaler What happens if EntityID is not indexed? I assume performance takes a hit?

Comment: @MiloUlver Yes, the query could become very slow. However, you described it as a "lookup table", so it should be indexed by definition.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use 1 `LEFT JOIN` ([demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/wE6CxjVT))

```
SELECT 
  D.*,
  MAX(CASE 
    WHEN D.ClientID = A.EntityID THEN CONCAT(A.Address, ', ', A.Country)
  END) AS ClientAddress,
  MAX(CASE 
    WHEN D.VendorID = A.EntityID THEN CONCAT(A.Address, ', ', A.Country)
  END) AS VendorAddress,
  MAX(CASE 
    WHEN D.FactoryID = A.EntityID THEN CONCAT(A.Address, ', ', A.Country)
  END) AS FactoryAddress
FROM DATA D
    LEFT JOIN ADDRESS A ON  A.EntityID IN (D.ClientID, D.VendorID, D.FactoryID)
GROUP BY D.WOID, D.ClientID, D.VendorID, D.FactoryID;
```

Or using sub-queries in `SELECT` statement ([demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/jxskFdcT))

```
SELECT 
  D.*,
  (SELECT CONCAT(A.Address, ', ', A.Country) 
   FROM ADDRESS A 
   WHERE D.ClientID = A.EntityID) AS ClientAddress,
  (SELECT CONCAT(A.Address, ', ', A.Country) 
   FROM ADDRESS A 
   WHERE D.VendorID = A.EntityID) AS VendorAddress,
  (SELECT CONCAT(A.Address, ', ', A.Country) 
   FROM ADDRESS A 
   WHERE D.FactoryID = A.EntityID) AS FactoryAddress
FROM DATA D;
```